# jQuery .stop() isn't stopping animation completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think the easiest way to demonstrate my problem is to make a short [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/QveqMo).
(Sorry I couldn't make a snippet. I copied the exact same code from codepen to the SO snippet, but it didn't perform the same way.)
But lets get to the problem:
So as you can see on my codepen, the "most visible" div gets centered after one second without scrolling.
Scroll to the very bottom and the footer should appear and it's not centering the previous div. I did that with that code:

```
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 20) {
    $("footer").addClass("footerVis");
    $("html, body").stop(true);
  } else {
    $("footer").removeClass("footerVis");
  }
```

I'm not sure if there would have been a better way to do that, but I just used `.stop()` to stop the scrolling animation to the previous div. However it works, but like every second it scrolls a bit up.
I guess that's because of the `setTimeout(function() {...}, 1000)` earlier in the JS to start the scrolling animation after one second. I can't explain why it scrolls a bit up every second tho...

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You probably want either `.stop(true, true)` or `.finish()`

Comment: @freedomn-m  Wouldn't the animation just finish (so scroll back up to the prev div) with these 2 options? Can't try it out atm

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. *"Scroll to the very bottom and the footer should appear and it's not centering the previous div."* this is what happens when `.stop(true,true)` but it may be happening too soon, so you may need to queue the centre animation  .

Comment: @freedomn-m  When you scroll to the very bottom of the page, the footer appears.. but every second it scrolls a little bit up. And I'm trying to achieve that this doesnt happen anymore